# Invalid kali linux login, what should I do?

Tags: kali-linux

Please what should I do as I have tried `root & toor` and it shows invalid login. I also tried `kali & kali` and it still showed invalid login. I have tried `ctrl + alt + F1` and  `dpkg --configure -a` but it still did not work. Should I reinstall my kali?

Comment: When you get a terminal window with Ctrl-Alt-F1, can you log in that way?

Comment: @John, I've tried both logins at the terminal windows and it still showed ```invalid login```

Comment: I'd boot into rescue mode, and try resetting the password. https://ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/